# JSRender: Any good documentation for JSRender

Tags: jsrender

we are using JSRender in our app which is a socail networking app. i have discovered that JSRender is very new in market and doesnot have a good documentation yet.....
If anyone has any infor where to find a good documentation please share the link...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I'm hesitant to call these articles 'documentation' these are a couple of links that have been helpful to me:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh882454.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh882454.aspx

Otherwise, it's Boris Moore's demo site on github:

http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/demos.html

I've found some nuggets in Boris' responses in the issues list as well:

https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues

---

UPDATE: Documentation is now at https://www.jsviews.com

Answer (score 2):

Here is a training course on [jsRender](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents?courseName=jsrender-fundamentals).

Answer (score 1):

I have just spent the last hour looking for a bit of documentation as well.....no luck.

Here is another useful article
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh975379.aspx

Answer (score 0):

the book 'jQuery Hotshot' employs jsrender in some of its chapters